# How do I correctly inherit from the same base class twice?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

This is our ideal inheritance hierarchy:

```
class Foobar;

class FoobarClient : Foobar;

class FoobarServer : Foobar;

class WindowsFoobar : Foobar;

class UnixFoobar : Foobar;

class WindowsFoobarClient : WindowsFoobar, FoobarClient;

class WindowsFoobarServer : WindowsFoobar, FoobarServer;

class UnixFoobarClient : UnixFoobar, FoobarClient;

class UnixFoobarServer : UnixFoobar, FoobarServer;
```

This is because the our inheritance hierarchy would try to inherit from `Foobar` twice, and as such, the compiler would complain of ambiguous references on any members of `Foobar`.

Allow me to explain why I want such a complex model. This is because we want to have the same variable accessible from `WindowsFoobar`, `UnixFoobar`, `FoobarClient`, and `FoobarServer`. This wouldn't be a problem, only I'd like to use multiple inheritance with any combination of the above, so that I can use a server/client function  on any platform, and also use a platform function on either client or server.

I can't help but feel this is a somewhat common issue with multiple inheritance... Am I approaching this problem from completely the wrong angle?

### Update 1:

Also, consider that we could use `#ifdef` to get around this, however, this will tend to yield very ugly code like such:

```
CFoobar::CFoobar()
#if SYSAPI_WIN32
: m_someData(1234)
#endif
{
}
```

... yuck!

### Update 2:

For those who want to read more into the background of this issue, I really suggest skimming over the appropriate [mailing list thread](http://groups.google.com/group/synergy-plus-dev/browse_thread/thread/481529a065d3362a). Thing start to get interesting around the 3rd post. Also there is a [related code commit](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/source/detail?r=344) with which you can see the real life code in question here.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you think REALLY hard about whether multiple inheritance is the right plan here. Every time I've ever used multiple inheritance, I've regretted it. I'd say that you should look closely at composition to solve this, or look at having the 'most derived' class be the only one inheriting from Foobar. The inheritance tree you've generated is going to be hard to understand and REALLY difficult to follow the operations of when you're trying to actually debug code.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of Michael, but this is the only solution I can imagine. Could you (or any one else) think of a model that is less contrived and meets the same goal of my simple requirement. I'm trying to create a model that minimizes code duplication.

Comment: See my follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990135/is-it-better-to-use-ifdef-or-multiple-inheritance-for-cross-compiling

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It *would* work, although you'd get two copies of the base `Foobar` class. To get a single copy, you'd need to use virtual inheritance. Read on multiple inheritance [here](http://jamesthornton.com/eckel/TICPP-2nd-ed-Vol-two/Chapter06.html).

```
class Foobar;

class FoobarClient : virtual public Foobar;

class FoobarServer : virtual public Foobar;

class WindowsFoobar : virtual public Foobar;

class UnixFoobar : virtual public Foobar;
```

However, there are many problems associated with multiple inheritance. If you really want to have the model presented, why not make `FoobarClient` and `FoobarServer` take a reference to `Foobar` at construction time, and then have `Foobar& FoobarClient/Server::getFoobar` ?

Composition is often a way out of multiple inheritance. Take a example now:

```
class WindowsFoobarClient : public WindowsFoobar 
{
    FoobarClient client;
public:
    WindowsFoobarClient() : client( this ) {}
    FoobarClient& getClient() { return client }
}
```

However [care must be taken](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.7) in using this in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for extending your answer to provide an alternative; I had not considered this.

Comment: Kornel, I ended up doing it this way - although I did it the other way around; I renamed `WindowsFoobar` to `WindowsFoobarUtil` and created an `m_util` member for `Foobar`. The `WindowsFoobarUtil` instance is created in the constructor of each platform client/server class (e.g. `WindowsFoobarClient`).

Answer (score 7):

What you are directly after here is *virtual inheritance* feature of C++. What you are in here for is a maintenance nightmare. This might not be a huge surprise since well-known authors like H. Sutter have been arguing against such use of inheritance for a while already. But this comes from direct experience with code like this. Avoid deep inheritance chains. Be very afraid of the `protected` keyword - it's use is very limited. This kind of design quickly gets out of hand - tracking down patterns of access to protected variable somewhere up the inheritance chain from lower level classes becomes hard, responsibilities of the code parts become vague, etc., and people who look at your code a year from now will hate you :)

Comment: +1 "and people who look at your code a year from now will hate you"

Answer (score 5):

You're in C++, you should get friendly with templates.  Using the template-argument-is-a-base-class pattern, you'll not need any multiple inheritance or redundant implementations.  It will look like this:

```
class Foobar {};

template <typename Base> class UnixFoobarAspect : public Base {};
template <typename Base> class WindowsFoobarAspect : public Base {};
template <typename Base> class FoobarClientAspect : public Base {};
template <typename Base> class FoobarServerAspect : public Base {};

typedef UnixFoobarAspect<FoobarClientAspect<Foobar>/*this whitespace not needed in C++0x*/> UnixFoobarClient;
typedef WindowsFoobarAspect<FoobarClientAspect<Foobar> > WindowsFoobarClient;
typedef UnixFoobarAspect<FoobarServerAspect<Foobar> > UnixFoobarServer;
typedef WindowsFoobarAspect<FoobarServerAspect<Foobar> > WindowsFoobarServer;
```

You might also consider using the curiously recurring template pattern instead of declaring abstract functions to avoid virtual function calls when the base class needs to call a function implemented in one of the specialized variants.

Comment: Um, don't you think this is going a little overboard for such a small example? Considering also that it will force to inline all of those classes?

Comment: Why do you think it is a small example?  The OP didn't provide the body for ANY of the classes, there could be, and probably are, dozens of member functions implemented at each level of the hierarchy.

It could be simplified, the bottom level of the hierarchy can be straight inheritance without using templates.

Yes, all the classes will get inlined during instantiation, which is usually a huge performance win compared to virtual calls.  You can still use explicit instantiation so the compiler only has to process the function bodies once, instead of every compilation unit where they are used.

Comment: This example is one of the ways to do a "policy-based design" (others don't use inheritance), and looking up information on PBD may provide you with useful insights and examples towards solving this kind of problem.

Comment: You've made WindowsAspect inherit from ServerAspect, which seems arbitrary. Why break the symmetry in one direction and not the other? Why is it better to introduce arbitrary relationships into the design, than it is to use multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 3):

Use virtual inheritance, in the declaration of `FoobarClient`, `FoobarServer`, `WindowsFoobar` and `UnixFoobar`, put the word `virtual` before the `Foobar` base class name.

This will ensure there is always a single instance of `Foobar` no matter how many times it appears in your base class hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=diamond+inheritance). Diamond inheritance is somewhat of contentuous issue and the proper solution dependes on individual situation.

I would like to comment on the Unix/Windows side of things. Generally one would `#ifndef` things out that are not appropriate for the particular platform. So you would end up with just `Foobar` compiled for either Windows or Unix using preprocessor directives, not `UnixFoobar` and `WindowsFoobar`. See how far you can get using that paradigm before exploring virtual inheritance.

Comment: We had previously used #ifdefs, but because of the amount of code, this has started to get very messy over the course of 10 years. I am using this as an experimental replacement for the #ifdef paradigm... but I'm very worried this will make the code more complex, which will defeat the purpose I think.

Comment: Right, sounds like a bit of a painful situation. I am not very familiar with cross compiling, it might pay off to see what patterns other people are using for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this example of composition and inheritance:

```
class Client_Base;
class Server_Base;

class Foobar
{
  Client_Base * p_client;
  Server_Base * p_server;
};

class Windows_Client : public Client_Base;
class Windows_Server : public Server_Base;

class Win32 : Foobar
{
  Win32()
  {
    p_client = new Windows_Client;
    p_server = new Windows_Server;
  }
};

class Unix_Client : public Client_Base;
class Unix_Server : public Server_Base;

class Unix : Foobar
{
  Unix()
  {
    p_client = new Unix_Client;
    p_server = new Unix_Server;
  }
};
```

Many experts have said that issues can be resolved with another level of indirection.

Comment: I still consider `#ifdef` to be severly evil, based on past experience.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing "illegal" about having the same base class twice. The final child class will just (literally) have multiple copies of the base class as part of it (including each variable in the base class, etc). It may result in some ambiguous calls to that base classes' functions, though, which you might have to resolve manually. This doesn't sound like what you want.

Consider composition instead of inheritance.

Also, virtual inheritance is a way to fold together the same base class which appears twice. If it really is just about data sharing, though, composition might make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variable with the qualified class name, but I forget the exact syntax.

However, this is one of the bad cases of using multiple inheritance that can cause you many difficulties. Chances are that you don't want to have things this way.

It's much more likely you want to have foobar privately inherited, have each subclass own a foobar, have foobar be a pure virtual class, or have the derived class own the things it currently defines or even define foobar on its own.