# virtual derivation & conversion ambiguous

Tags: c++, virtual

I'm learning now the different situations of ambiguity in the virtual derivation on C++.
But I have an error of Ambiguity in my code and I don't understand it's reason...

> Here's my Code :

```
class V {
    public:
        int v ;
};

class A {
    public:
        int a ;
};

class B : public A, public virtual V {

};

class C : public A, public virtual V {

};

class D : public B, public C {
    public:
        void f() ;
};

void g() {
    D d ;
    B* pb = &d ;  // No Problem
    A* pa = &d ;  // Error: 'A' is ambiguous base of 'D'
    V* pv = &d ;  // No Problem
}
```

I don't understand why do I have this error however I don't have errors for the other affectations.

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely expected in cases of [multiple inheritance](http://jamesthornton.com/eckel/TICPP-2nd-ed-Vol-two/Chapter06.html). What we have here is a case of Diamond inheritance. D now has two copies of A, one inherited from B, and one inherited from C. You need to specify which of B or C the members of A exposed to D come from.

See: [Using C++, how do I correctly inherit from the same base class twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990032/using-c-how-do-i-correctly-inherit-from-the-same-base-class-twice)

You might consider:

- Using virtual inheritance:

  `class B : public virtual  A, public virtual V {...};`

  `class C : public virtual A, public virtual V {...};`
- Using composition as a way out of multiple inheritance.

I suggest reading [Solving the Diamond Problem with Virtual Inheritance](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html)

Comment: Thank you. But Both of them are inherited from A. So what's the problem whith this affectation ? Thank you

Comment: @Mehdi - D *cannot* inherit two instances of A. Think about it - if A contains a public property "a", then both B and C each have a property "a". Now D has two properties "a" - which one should the compiler use? It can't just merge them - it's not that simple. That's why it can't compile.